# Integral Ideals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ideals

> Any nonempty set of integers $J$ that fulfills the following conditions is called an *integral ideal*:
>
> (i)   If $n$ and $m$ are in $J$, then $n+m$ and $n-m$ are in $J$.
>   (ii) If $n$ is in $J$ and $r$ is an integer, then $rn$ is in $J$.
>
> Let $J_m$ be the set of all integers that are integral multiples of a particular integer $m$. Prove that $J_m$ is an integral ideal.

I am not sure where to even begin this

Comment: Prove that the sum and the difference of two multiples of $m$ are again multiples of $m$. Also prove that a multiple of a multiple of $m$ is a multiple of $m$.

Comment: This is quite elementary using the definition (btw, (i) implies (ii)). The interesting part is that the converse is also true: Any integral ideal is in fact formed of the multiples of some integer $m$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you only need $n - m \in J$ in (i), since $n \in J$ implies $0 = n - n \in J$ implies $-m = 0 - m \in J$ implies $n + m = n - (-m) \in J$.

That being said, note that any element of $J_m$ is of the form $am$ for $a \in \Bbb Z$.
So, if $am, bm \in J_m$, then we have $am -bm = (a - b)m \in J_m$.  This knocks down criterion (i).  As for (ii), note that for $am \in J_m$, $n \in \Bbb Z$, $n(am) = (na)m \in J_m$ as well.

Let's call it a wrap, it's in the can!

Hope this helps.  Cheers, and

Fiat Lux!